# Asset Pipeline failing when deploying to Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, rubygems, bundler, asset-pipeline

When I deploy to Heroku I get this error messages:

```
Connecting to database specified by DATABASE_URL
   rake aborted!
   could not connect to server: Connection refused
   Is the server running on host "127.0.0.1" and accepting
   TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

The curious thing is that this only started to happen after I add `gem 'impressionist'` to the Gemfile. Locally there are not any problems. Commenting out the gem resolves it for deployment.

The error received from Heroku is [well documented](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails-asset-pipeline), but nothing there gives me any clue to what is causing the fail.

[The Impressionist gem](https://github.com/charlotte-ruby/impressionist) is fairly popular, and I haven't seen any similar issues deriving from it, so I'm skeptical that the gem is the root to the problem.

**Update**

Here's the complete Gemfile, just to show that it's a normal app that works fine in deployment (until the above mentioned gem is added).

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.13'
gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '3.0.1'
gem 'jquery-rails', '2.2.1'
gem 'impressionist'
# gem 'will_paginate'

group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.6'
  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
  gem 'jquery-ui-rails'
end

group :development, :test do
  gem 'quiet_assets'
  gem 'webrick', '~> 1.3.1'
  gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.7'
  gem 'hirb'
end

group :production do
  gem 'thin'
  gem 'pg', '0.12.2'
end
```

Comment: Have you added the user-env-compile flag as mentioned the asset guide? https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails-asset-pipeline

Comment: Is your postgresql server running? `ps aux | grep postgres`

Comment: @friism no I haven't. As you can see in the update, the app is normally working fine, so I don't know if that is a meaningful solution?

Comment: @Vimsha Locally I run SQLite3. The app and database is running just fine if I remove the gem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The 'issue' was that Impressionist sets up db configuration on the fly, Therefore it needs to load a DB adapter. Let's use ActiveRecord as an example. When it tries to load ActiveRecord::Base it raises an exception that Heroku informs you with that message, because you're not connected to the DB yet.
Devise has had this issue plataformatec/devise#1339

I added cancan gem and removed impressionist and it raised the same error.

Fortunately there is a solution:

```
# config/application.rb
# Forces application to not load models or access the DB when precompiling
# assets
config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false
```

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest filing an issue on that gem's GitHub project. Most likely it is trying to connect to the database using the initialization process and, because the database is not available by that stage, it is failing.

You may be able to solve this problem by adding this line to your `config/environments/production.rb` file:

```
 config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false
```

Comment: Unfortunately adding the line above didn't solve it.

I have now filed an issue on GitHub. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

change this in your production.rb file

```
config.assets.compile = false
```

then precompile assets locally

```
RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile
```

A public/assets directory will be created. Inside this directory you’ll find a manifest.yml which includes the md5sums of the compiled assets in Rails 3. In Rails 4 the file will be manifest-.json. Adding public/assets to your git repository will make it available to Heroku.

```
git add public/assets
git commit -m "vendor compiled assets"
```

after this push the code